# Array.Find() not assigning a return value

Tags: c#, arrays

I am attempting to use `Array.Find()` to return a structure, from an array of structures, and assign it to a structure named Result. However, Result's values never change from null (I ran it though the debugger twice). My code is posted below, can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string formName = textBoxName.Text;
    Info Result = Array.Find<Info>(Data, p => p.Name == formName);
    textBoxHeight.Text = Result.Height;
}
```

I'm trying to search an array of structs (`Info[]`) named `Data`, for an element x where `Info[x].Name` is the same as the values entered into another text box.

The debugger shows that it managed to find the element, but the element was never assigned to Result.

Comment: I see! Sorry this is my first time posting.

Comment: It is okay, no need to apologize. Stack Exchange is a really good resource but it takes a little time to understand how to use it effectively. Don't get discouraged, just learn and do better next time. No big deal.

Comment: Are you sure the names are actually equal? Is the casing the same in both strings? Are you sure there are no whitespaces in the textbox?

Comment: There's very high chance that it's not actually the same, maybe there are some characters that are not visible? Try comparing binary values in debugger.

Comment: Indeed, also try some overloads for `string.Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a struct Array.Find returns a non-null object even if it can't find an entry in Data - if however you drill-down into the properties of this object you'll see its inner properties are null. Could this be what you're seeing? If you switch from using a struct to a class then result will return null as expected.

If case doesn't matter I'd use equals() with an invariant case lookup. This way an item in Data with a name of for example *Test* would be found when entering *test*, *TEsT* and *tEsT*: Using your existing code it would have to be exactly *Test* to find it.

```
Info Result = Array.Find<Info>(Data, p => p.Name.Equals(formName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You could also strip whitespace in-case the user happened to add some spaces by mistake:

```
Info Result = Array.Find<Info>(Data, p => p.Name.Equals(formName.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You could also use LINQ instead. It looks cleaner in my opinion. Just make sure you add a reference to LINQ at the top of your code:

```
using System.Linq;
```

```
Info Result = Data.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(formName.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```